# Can I create a predicate that will accept both functions and functors as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on a problem in C++ that involves lots of subset and transformation operations on a large quantity of data. To that end, I've created a map function and something like list comprehensions. I've found that a bunch of the predicates I'm writing also have inverses, so I'd need to write:

```
template <typename type_t>
bool HasTenFoo(const type_t &t) {
  return t.foo >= 10.0;
}
```

and

```
template <typename type_t>
bool DoesntHaveTenFoo(const type_t &t) {
  return t.foo < 10.0;
}
```

Neither of those is a real example, but they're representative. I'm also using a fair number of functors like:

```
class HasEnoughFoo {
public:
  HasEnoughFoo (double bar) { this->bar = bar; }
  template<typename type_t>
  bool operator()(const type_t &t) const { return t.foo >= bar; }
private:
  double bar;
};
```

some of which should have inverses as well. Rather than duplicate code unnecessarily, I'd like to write a functor that takes a predicate as an argument and returns the (value of the) inverse of that predicate. My fist cut at one is below:

```
/* -- Returns the opposite of some other predicate -------------------------- */

template<typename predicate_t>
class Not {
public:
  template <typename predicate_t>
  Not(predicate_t *p) { predicate = p; }

  template <typename type_t>
  bool operator()(const type_t &t) const {
    return !(*predicate)(t);
  }

private:
  predicate_t *predicate;
};
```

I would call that with something like:

```
new_list = old_list.subset(Not<HasEnoughFoo>(&HasEnoughFoo(10.0));
```

or

```
new_list = old_list.subset(Not<HasTenFoo>(&HasTenFoo));
```

That seems to work well when `predicate_t` is a functor like `HasEnoughFoo`, but fails when `predicate_t` refers to a regular function like `HasTenFoo`.

Visual Studio complains that `'HasTenFoo' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'predicate_t'`. Is there any way to write a Not() predicate that will work with functors and functions or am I doomed to write dozens of predicates and their inverses as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of your code made to work (I removed the `foo` member, so it would work with just doubles).

```
template <typename type_t>
bool HasTenFoo(const type_t &t) {
  return t >= 10.0;
}

class HasEnoughFoo {
public:
  HasEnoughFoo (double bar) { this->bar = bar; }
  template<typename type_t>
  bool operator()(const type_t &t) const { return t >= bar; }
private:
  double bar;
};


template<typename predicate_t>
class Not {
public:
  Not(predicate_t p): predicate(p) { }

  template <typename type_t>
  bool operator()(const type_t &t) const {
    return !predicate(t);
  }

private:
  predicate_t predicate;
};

template <class predicate_type>
Not<predicate_type> Negate(predicate_type p)
{
    return p;
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << Negate(HasTenFoo<double>)(11.0) << '\n';
    std::cout << Negate(HasEnoughFoo(13.0))(11.0) << '\n';
}
```

Some important notes:

Not's constructor uses the initialization list. This removes the requirement that the predicate type has a default constructor (which HasEnoughFoo doesn't have).

You definitely don't want to mess with pointers to predicates. Function objects are supposed to be light-weight objects that can be copied without a worry.

Because Not is a template class, with a potentially complicated template argument, but you'd normally just use it as a temporary (as an unnamed argument to a function taking a predicate), add a template function that deduces the complicated type for you (trick used all over the standard library) - here `Negate`.

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize that using an initializer list would remove the requirement for a default constructor (which is what I was passing by pointer instead of by value). The Negate function to hide the template complexity is beautiful as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have two big problems.

The first issue is that `HasTenFoo` is a template function. Templates don't actually exist; you can't take the address of one, since it doesn't exist. Instantiations of templates do exist, however. `&HasTenFoo` is illegal, `&HasTenFoo<Bar>` is legal. `HasTenFoo<Bar>` refers to a specific instance of the `HasTenFoo` template.

The second issue is that the `Not` class's template parameter has to be the **type** of the function you're passing it. If you're giving it `HasTenFoo<Bar>`, the template parameter should be `bool(*)(const Bar&)`.

So, the correct version would be

```
Not<bool(*)(const Bar&)>(&HasTenFoo<Bar>)
```

Note that for this to work for both functions and functors, you would have to store a copy of the object/function, not a pointer to them. This is the preferred approach; all standard library functions that take functors keep an internal copy.

Comment: predicate is a pointer to predicate_t. In my opinion it's unnecessary and it would make things easier if the predicate was stored by value. But it isn't. Shouldn't the template argument be a function instead of a pointer to a function then?

Comment: Functions are pointers. &HasTenFoo<Bar> is equivalent to HasTenFoo<Bar>. I was just copying his example.

Comment: Yes, but in Not<bool(\*)(const Bar&)> private member predicate is of type bool(****)(const Bar&), isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

There's the built in [not1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/not1/) predicate.  It takes a predicate and negates it.  This will work with any predicate that derives from unary_predicate.  This would remove the need for your hand rolled predicate.

Some combination of that and [ptr_fun](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/ptr_fun/) might achieve what you want.

Edit,
Something like this might work (warning, totally untested, not even sure this will compile)

```
int factorial (int x) {
    ....
}
std::transform (d.begin (), d.end (), v.begin (), std::ptr_fun (factorial));
std::transform (d.begin (), d.end (), v.begin (), not1(std::ptr_fun (factorial)));
```

Comment: My reading of the documentation suggests that not1 will only work with functors. Does it work with free functions as well?

Comment: @Bill Carey, ptr_fun can be used to convert a free function to a functor.  I've never used it, so can't provide any sample code.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try. Haven't dug around in the <functional> header as much as I should!

Comment: @Bill Carey, I've added an edit that shows roughly how this would work for you.

Comment: This usage is correct, and in fact is the reason `ptr_fun` exists. One important note is that for member functions, you need to use `mem_fun_ref` instead.

Comment: This is a good example too, though you might want to change the second bit to something else, as not1's meant to work with predicates, not transformations, I think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost::lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/lambda.html). It allows you to construct predicates and other functors using little code.

Answer (score 0):

You've done it wrong. The function object idiom accepts function pointers or function objects. In addition, you improperly took the address of a template function. You didn't specify the type. Furthermore, as far as I know, instantiating template operators like operator() requires the explicit .operator() syntax, which most will not use. Also, you generated your function object wrong. Let me show you.

```
template<typename type_t> class HasEnoughFoo {
public:
  HasEnoughFoo (double bar) { this->bar = bar; }
  bool operator()(const type_t &t) const { return t.foo >= bar; }
private:
  double bar;
};

template<typename predicate_t, typename type_t>
class Not {
public:
  Not(const predicate_t& p) { predicate = p; }

  bool operator()(const type_t &t) const {
    return !(predicate(t));
  }

private:
  predicate_t predicate;
};
```

Now this functionoid can accept function pointers or function objects that accept the correct arguments.

```
typedef type_t MyCustomType;
new_list = old_list.subset(Not<HasEnoughFoo<type_t>>(&HasEnoughFoo<type_t>(10.0));
new_list = old_list.subset(Not<decltype(HasTenFoo<&type_t)>>(&HasTenFoo<type_t>));
```

Essentially:
Put template operators on the function class's type, NOT on the operator or constructors.
Functions MUST have their full template arguments to have their address taken- how else does the compiler know what function's address you want?

Excuse my use of decltype, I couldn't be bothered to type out the function signature. Insert actual signature here.

Answer (score 0):

Functions *are* functors, which means that if you do everything correctly, your `Not` template  should work as is.

Firstly, there's an obvious error in your `Not` template declaration - some strange extra `template` around constructor. This is how it should have looked like

```
template<typename predicate_t>
class Not {
public:
  Not(predicate_t *p) { predicate = p; }

  template <typename type_t>
  bool operator()(const type_t &t) const {
    return !(*predicate)(t);
  }

private:
  predicate_t *predicate;
};
```

What that extra `template` was doing there I don't know. If you were trying to make a template conversion constructor, you were doing it incorrectly. Maybe what you are posting is not the real code.

Now, to use that with your `HasTenFoo` we'd simply do it as follows

```
new_list = old_list.subset(Not<bool(const LIST_ELEMENT&)>(&HasTenFoo));
```

or, to make it a bit more readable

```
typedef bool OrdinaryFuncPredicate(const LIST_ELEMENT&);
new_list = old_list.subset(Not<OrdinaryFuncPredicate>(&HasTenFoo));
```

Note the type used as the template argument for `Not` template. What you were using in your example made no sense (it was a value, not a type, which exactly is what the compiler explicitly told you). Since you are using a function as a predicate, you have to specify the *function type* as the template argument. This function type should take the list element type as function argument. It is not clear from your original post what the list element type is, so I just used `LIST_ELEMENT` name as a substitute.